# analysis of two stage preampplifier

Tags: circuit-analysis, amplifier

I found this circuit in an old book.  It is a two stage audio amplifier

I wanted to try it but I didn't know how to do the dc analysis.

I couldn't find any current.
Could you help me to find a first one?  After that, I can find the rest.

[image]

Comment: This circuit has a DC-feedback loop through R2. It is (as far as I know) almost impossible to find the point where the loop stabilizes itself in one attempt. What I would do is **make an assumption** like Q2 has \$I_c\$ = 1 mA. Then go through the loop and see if that is a proper solution. You might find that Q2's \$I_c\$ needs to be larger or smaller. After a few iterations you should get close. For confirmation, use a circuit simulator! The high value (1k ohm) supply resistor makes things more complicated! I would start with R8 = 0 ohm and see what I get. Then try again with R 8 = 1 kohm.

Comment: this is what i thought about . because of the feedback i couldn't know where to start so i assumed a value but i asked to make sure if there is a way to know i missed . thank u so much and for R8 i thought it is unnecessary too. thanks

Comment: I recall that circuit from highschool. Its a PRE_AMP, and will not directly drive a loudspeaker.

Answer (score 4):

Start by recognizing that if Q1 is cut off, R1 is the sole source of base current for Q2. In order to establish equilibrium, the voltage across R7 must rise to the point where Q1 starts to conduct and divert some of that base current away. This establishes a minimum current through R7.

There is also a maximum current through R7 established by the series connection of R8, R5, R6 and R7 (assuming Q2 is saturated). It's probably safe to assume that the quiescent point for Q2 is somewhere close to the midpoint of these two current values.

The current through R6 + R7 determines the emitter voltage of Q2, which also establishes the base voltage of Q2 and the collector voltage of Q1.

This gives us the collector current of Q1.

The collector current of Q1, along with R4, determine the maximum current through R3. There's also a small contribution of the base current through R2.

Are these hints enough to get you started?

Answer (score 3):

A versatile imagination is worth developing and it pays off in situations like this. For example, a brute force method would be to set up the nodal equations (with simplifying assumptions) and solve. But this doesn't really help that much if all you have is a piece of paper and pen (or sand and your fingers) to work from.

I don't really like Dave's approach here, though. It's an obvious approach, taken by observing that \$Q_2\$ can get base current via \$R_1\$, but to me it is both an annoying and very unsatisfying approach. It would seem that there should be some more direct route. And luckily, there is.

So I'll take a much simpler tactic, because you asked for just one node and doing so will help make my point clearer.

---

Let's start by working out \$Q_1\$. Rather than assuming it is cutoff, we'll assume the circuit was actually designed by someone intelligent enough to do so and that \$Q_1\$ actually does operate in active mode. I'll choose to solve the collector voltage for you, here. Much else will be obvious in the process, too. So you get a lot from it.

Here is the ***direct*** approach to solving the operating point for the collector voltage (\$V_{\text{C}_1}\$) of \$Q_1\$. I'll start out by using the schematic editor to put in your schematic and some added labels for clarity:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feMQbc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Let's now start at the collector of \$Q_1\$ and do a walk-around, updating equations as we go:

1. We know that the emitter of \$Q_2\$ is one \$V_\text{BE}\$ below \$V_{\text{C}_1}\$. So \$V_{\text{E}_2}=V_{\text{C}_1}-V_{\text{BE}_2}\$.
2. We know that \$R_6\$ and \$R_7\$ form a voltage divider. So it follows that \$V_\text{FB}=V_{\text{E}_2}\cdot\frac{R_7}{R_6+R_7}=\left(V_{\text{C}_1}-V_{\text{BE}_2}\right)\cdot\frac{R_7}{R_6+R_7}\$.
3. We know that \$R_2\$ will add another voltage drop, based upon the required base current of \$Q_1\$. So it follows that \$V_{\text{B}_1}=V_\text{FB}-I_{\text{B}_1}\cdot R_2=\left(V_{\text{C}_1}-V_{\text{BE}_2}\right)\cdot\frac{R_7}{R_6+R_7}-I_{\text{B}_1}\cdot R_2\$.
4. We know that the emitter of \$Q_1\$ is one \$V_\text{BE}\$ below \$V_{\text{B}_1}\$. So it follows that \$V_{\text{E}_1}=V_{\text{B}_1}-V_{\text{BE}_1}=\left(V_{\text{C}_1}-V_{\text{BE}_2}\right)\cdot\frac{R_7}{R_6+R_7}-I_{\text{B}_1}\cdot R_2-V_{\text{BE}_1}\$.
5. We know that the \$V_{\text{E}_1}\$ causes a current in \$R_3\$. So (ignoring \$R_4\$) we know that \$I_{\text{E}_1}=\frac{V_{\text{E}_1}}{R_3}=\frac{\left(V_{\text{C}_1}-V_{\text{BE}_2}\right)\cdot\frac{R_7}{R_6+R_7}-I_{\text{B}_1}\cdot R_2-V_{\text{BE}_1}}{R_3}\$.
6. We know that \$I_{\text{E}_1}\approx I_{\text{C}_1}\$. So it follows that \$V_{\text{C}_1}\approx V_\text{PWR}-R_1\cdot I_{\text{E}_1}\approx V_\text{PWR}-\frac{R_1}{R_3}\cdot \left[\left(V_{\text{C}_1}-V_{\text{BE}_2}\right)\cdot\frac{R_7}{R_6+R_7}-I_{\text{B}_1}\cdot R_2-V_{\text{BE}_1}\right]\$.
7. We also know that \$V_{\text{E}_2}\$ causes a current in \$R_6+R_7\$. So we know that \$I_{\text{E}_2}=\frac{V_{\text{E}_2}}{R_6+R_7}=\frac{V_{\text{C}_1}-V_{\text{BE}_2}}{R_6+R_7}\$.
8. We know that \$I_{\text{E}_2}\approx I_{\text{C}_2}\$. So it follows that \$V_\text{PWR}\approx 12\:\text{V}-R_8\cdot \left(I_{\text{E}_1}+I_{\text{E}_2}\right)\\\quad\quad\approx 12\:\text{V}-R_8\cdot \left(\frac{\left(V_{\text{C}_1}-V_{\text{BE}_2}\right)\cdot\frac{R_7}{R_6+R_7}-I_{\text{B}_1}\cdot R_2-V_{\text{BE}_1}}{R_3}+\frac{V_{\text{C}_1}-V_{\text{BE}_2}}{R_6+R_7}\right)\$.

Substituting #8 into #6 above:

$$V_{\text{C}_1}\approx 12\:\text{V}-R_8\cdot \left(\tfrac{\left(V_{\text{C}_1}-V_{\text{BE}_2}\right)\cdot\frac{R_7}{R_6+R_7}-I_{\text{B}_1}\cdot R_2-V_{\text{BE}_1}}{R_3}+\tfrac{V_{\text{C}_1}-V_{\text{BE}_2}}{R_6+R_7}\right)-\\\quad \frac{R_1}{R_3}\cdot \left[\left(V_{\text{C}_1}-V_{\text{BE}_2}\right)\cdot\frac{R_7}{R_6+R_7}-I_{\text{B}_1}\cdot R_2-V_{\text{BE}_1}\right]$$

For now, let's assume that \$I_{\text{B}_1}\approx 0\:\text{A}\$, which then allows a simpler solution for \$V_{\text{C}_1}\$:

$$V_{\text{C}_1}=\tfrac{12\:\text{V}\cdot R_3\cdot\left[R_6+R_7\right]+V_{\text{BE}_1}\cdot\left(\left[R_1+R_8\right]\cdot\left[R_6+R_7\right]\right)+V_{\text{BE}_2}\cdot\left(R_1\cdot R_7+R_3\cdot R_8+R_7\cdot R_8\right)}{R_3\cdot \left(R_6+R_7+R_8\right)+R_7\cdot\left(R_1+R_8\right)}$$

From the above and substituting in the various values (and I chose to use \$700\:\text{mV}\$ for both \$V_\text{BE}\$ values), I get: \$V_{\text{C}_1}\approx 2.44\:\text{V}\$.

Note that I've completely ignored the influence of \$R_4\$ as well as setting the base current for \$Q_1\$ to zero. Running this schematic on LTspice and using a variety of BJT parameters to verify the range of operating points one might likely find, I get a result of \$V_{\text{C}_1}\approx 2.34\:\text{V}\$. In other words, with a variety of simplifying assumptions about \$V_\text{BE}\$ and \$I_{\text{B}_1}\$, as well as ignoring \$R_4\$ and the effect of \$R_2\$ on the divider voltage at the midpoint between \$R_6\$ and \$R_7\$, I still get within \$100\:\text{mV}\$.

Not bad.

---

Please note that this is just a mental walking-around. It just flows out. All you have to do is to keep plugging along. There's a small bit of tedium about it. But as you can see, there's no need for complex matrix set-ups with lots of equations developed from nodal or mesh analysis. Nor do you need to start with incorrect assumptions that you'll later have to remedy. You can just drill into some random spot and walk around from there, developing refinements as you proceed.

It's likely that you will finally get an equation where the left side variable is found in several places on the right side, requiring some algebraic work. But it's just a single equation, at least. And solvable.

---

I haven't solved any of the other node voltages for you. But I think the above should take you very far in getting what else you want to know about the DC operating point. For example, now having an approximation for \$V_{\text{C}_1}\$ you can now immediately work out an approximate value for \$V_{\text{E}_2}\$ and from there the approximate emitter current for \$Q_2\$. Etc. The key to the Gordian knot has been found and now the rest of the information just falls apart into pieces almost as fast as you can write them down.

Answer (score 2):

To do a DC analysis, you need to think of the circuit if it is in the steady state condition. Capacitors in the steady state condition do not have currents flowing across them, so they can be considered open, if so the circuit then becomes this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This won't be able to drive a speaker with R5 pullup at 2k2.

So what's the point?  Anything less than 2k2 load can starve the Q2 of current on large swings.